Postgresql + Opensearch
I'm trying to synchronize my postgresql database with opensearch. Find a debezium for that task, but it only has elasticsearch connector. What should I use to sync my data between them?
I tried to use elasticsearch connector for debezium, but it fails with an error. I also tried to use Aiven Opensearch connector - no result (perhaps I didn't find a right way).

your question needs to have more clarity. It must include the error you are facing, what all steps you did to integrate debezium to reach the error. While doing this all, what was the documentation you had referred.
